# Javascript Concatenate Strings based on conditions

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

Is there a good way to accomplish this Javascript?

Basically I want something where the values of the fields are concatenate into a single field with comma between the values.  Figure something simple like this

var a
var b
var c

allfieldvalue = a + ","b + ","c

My issue is I need to build condition in order for them to be put into allfieldvalue.  So if var a = true, var b = false, and var c = true, then allfieldvalue = a +","c.  Keep in mind, there could 20 different var.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: What condition exactly?

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Put them in an array and `filter()` to get all the true values. Then use `.join()` to concatenate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the goal is a string containing the *names of variables* that are true, use this approach:

Make the variables into object props...

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = true;

let object = { a, b, c };  // produces { a: true, b: false, c: true }
```

Filter that object to exclude false values:

```
object = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object).filter(([k,v]) => v) // produces { a: true, c: true }
)
```

Concat the keys:

```
let string = Object.keys(object).join(',');  // produces "a,c"
```

Demo

```js
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = true;

let object = { a, b, c }; 

object = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object).filter(([k,v]) => v) 
)

let string = Object.keys(object).join(','); 
console.log(string)
```

Comment: This is actually what I wanted.  Based on field value condition being true, put all the variable name into one field.  This is only my 3rd day of trying to learn Javascript and didn't even know these option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put them in an array, then use `.filter()` and `.join()` to concatenate the true values.

```js
let a = true;
let b = false;
let c = true;

let all_vars = [a, b, c];
let result = all_vars.filter(e => e).join(',');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Produces `'true, true'` which I think (I might be wrong) isn't the OP's intent.  I think the OP wants `'a,c'`, which would suggest placing the vars in an object and filtering entires

Comment: That's what I suspect as well, but the question isn't clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, It depends on what's in the variable, if you want a boolean and display it, you could do something like this :

```
function myFunc(...variables) {    
    console.log(variables.filter(v => v != false).join(", "));
}
let a = true;
let b = false;
let c  = true
console.log(myFunc(a,b,c));
```